# Using OR function in excel changes expected behavior

Tags: arrays, excel, function

I'm trying to implement a variation of the function found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/692364/list-values-based-on-criteria).

I have a table with a list of people, and how many days in each month they have turned in their homework. In a separate table on the right, I want a list of names of the people who did their homework every day for at least one month. Then, I want the number of months they did their homework every day listed next to their name.

My current formula works for displaying names when calculating for a single month so far:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$6=31,IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,A$2:A$6)=0,ROW(A$2:A$6)-
ROW(A$2)+1)),1)),"")
```

[image]

However, I want a list of people who did homework every day in ANY month listed so I tried using an OR() function in place of just B$2:B$6=31:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(OR(B$2:B$6=31,C$2:C$6=28),IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,A$2:A$6)=0,
ROW(A$2:A$6)-ROW(A$2)+1)),1)),"")
```

However, now it spits out all the names into the rightmost list regardless, and if I stretch the formula down to more cells, it populates a 0 after all the names, too.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: I guess you had the forethought to use `=EOMONTH(DATE(2016, COLUMN(A:A), 1), 0)` in B1 and fill right then use a custom date format of *mmm*...? It kinda looks like you typed whatever you wanted into row 1.

Comment: Even after fixing that, it doesn't fix my original issue: how to check over a range of months if people have done a full months-worth of homework.

Comment: You needed to know the correct number of days in each month. That function now allows you to use `B2=DAY(B1)` or `C4=DAY(C1)` so that should get you on the way to solving this. You asked *'What should I be doing differently?'* and I've just shown you.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the OR() function as far as I understand what you're saying. Now my function looks like this in cell G3:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,SMALL(IF(OR(B$2:B$6=DAY(B$1),C$2:C$6=DAY(C$1),D$2:D$6=DAY(D$1),E$2:E$6=DAY(E$1)),IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,A$2:A$6)=0,ROW(A$2:A$6)-ROW(A$2)+1)),1)),"")`

Comment: It should list everyone once, but it ends up listing everyone over 30 times.